# How do I align a tikz node properly in a rotated tree?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I have a short rotated tree where one node has two child nodes that both then have the same child. However, the shared child on level three is not aligned properly. I have been playing around with above=Xem for the 3rd level but it's always kind of off.

Is there a way to automatically align it properly with the first level?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=20em,rotate=90,
edge from parent/.style={->,thick,draw=black,line width = 0.5em,shorten >=8pt, shorten <=8pt},
level 1/.style={sibling distance=15em},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=15em},
every node/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,thick,scale=2, align=center, line width=0.15em,text centered}]]
\node[text width=12em] {\textbf{1st level}}
    child { node {\textbf{2nd level 1}}
        child { node[name=3] {\textbf{3rd level}} } }
    child { node[name=2] {\textbf{2nd level 2}}
        };
\draw[->,thick,draw=black,line width = 0.5em] (2) edge (3);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: resulting graph]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please always (if possible) provide complete small document (called MWE: Minimal Working Example) beginning width `\documentclass[...]{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`, which reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want horizontal alignment between level 1 and 3, you can code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc
    ,positioning}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=20em,rotate=90,
        edge from parent/.style={->,thick,draw=black,line width = 0.5em,shorten >=8pt, shorten <=8pt},
        level 1/.style={sibling distance=15em},
        level 2/.style={sibling distance=15em},
        every node/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,thick,scale=2, align=center, line width=0.15em,text centered}]]
        \node[text width=12em, name=1] {\textbf{1st level}}
        child { node [name=2-1]{\textbf{2nd level 1}}
            %         child { node[name=3] {\textbf{3rd level}} } 
        }
        child { node[name=2-2] {\textbf{2nd level 2}}
        };
        % \draw[->,thick,draw=black,line width = 0.5em] (2-2) edge (3);
        \node [right=20em of $(2-1)!.5!(2-2)$, anchor=center] (3) {\textbf{3rd level}};
        % \node [right=20em of 1|-2-1, anchor=center] (3) {\textbf{3rd level}}; % <-- or
        \draw[->,thick,draw=black,line width = 0.5em] (2-1) edge (3);
        \draw[->,thick,draw=black,line width = 0.5em] (2-2) edge (3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1! Apparently I misunderstand a question :-(. I will correct only solution with using `forest`  ...

Comment: @Zarko : is it possible within tree?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. See my first part of answer, which contain cleaned OP code (frankly said, it is awful). There is in `edge from parent` option `line width=2mm, `. You only need to change it or replace with `thick` or `very tick`.

Comment: @Zarko Thank you for the edited answer, closer to OP. My solution is only partially `tree` ;)

Comment: Just now I edit my answer and made further step in clearing OP code. It may be now be of some help in your answer. ALso I add simple solution using `forest`.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**

In the first let me clean up your code that it can be used for effort to find solution for your tree drawn by pure `tikz`. After removing all clutter and doubled specifications and contradictions in style definitions, it is:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
                   grow = east, % <--- tree is not rotate but grow to east!
             arr/.style = {draw, ->,line width=1mm,
                           shorten >=8pt, shorten <=8pt},
edge from parent/.style = {arr},
      every node/.style = {draw, rounded corners, thick, font=\bfseries, anchor=east},
         level distance = 20em,
       sibling distance = 15em,
                        ]
\node   {1st level}
    child { node {2nd level 1}
        child { node[name=3] {3rd level} } }
    child { node[name=2] {2nd level 2}
        };
\draw[arr] (2) edge (3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, it *not solve your problem*, but make a step to clear starting point in searching solution using `tikz` trees. Such solution is already given in the other answer, so let me suggest solution which use  `forest` package:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {
% nodes 
    draw, rounded corners, 
    minimum height=3ex, 
    minimum width=6em,
    font=\bfseries,
% tree
    grow' = 0,
    parent anchor=east,
    child  anchor=west,
    /tikz/arr/.style = {ultra thick, -{Straight Barb[angle=60:2pt 3]}, % <---
                        shorten >=3pt, shorten <=3pt},  % <---
    edge={arr}, 
    s sep=12mm,
    l sep=18mm,
        }
[1st level 
    [2nd level 2, name=n1]
    [2nd level 1
        [3rd level, name=n2]
        [,phantom]             % <---
    ]
]
\draw[arr]   (n1.east) -- (n2.west);
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]